# Define multiple variables using for loop on python

Tags: python, for-loop, variables, pyqt5, qt-designer

I am a beginner in python coding. I have a couple of questions:

#### Question 1: How Can I define multiple variables using for-loop in Python

```
global I1_1
global I1_2
global I1_3
global I1_4
global I1_5
global I1_6
```

#### Questions 2: How can I call multiple objects using the for-loop.

For example, I have these objects:

```
lineEdit_1
lineEdit_2
...
lineEdit_100
```

I would like to call everyone of them in a for loop. I tried to look for something similar online but I didnt find. My first thought was to define a range for a variable i (1-100) then call lineEdit_i. Any idea?

Comment: This post might help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41645898/using-a-loop-to-create-and-assign-multiple-variables-python

Comment: Don't do that. Put all of this variables in a list or an array instead

Comment: Use `global()['varname'] = value` in a loop. The previous question *is not* clear on this is possible. Adding answer to that - also, it's not exactly clear that the two question are asking the same thing, it seem to me the previous one is broader and this is a more specific case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're talking about dynamically creating variables, which to my understanding you cannot do. What you can do, however, is leverage the python data structure of lists. Initialize a list by setting a variable like `my_list = []` then you can `.append()` any of your variables to the list, use a for-loop to loop through all your variables, and do whatever you need to in your loop.

Comment: You can, use `globals()['varname'] = value` in a loop.

Comment: Actually, in python you *can* create variables (with various scopes) dynamically. But usually it's better to use a dict or list instead.

Comment: I'm sure there is a way to do it dynamically, but chances are if you are resorting to that, you're missing a much easier way to write your code.